# Can i declare a local variable in a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, indexing, graph, lua, grid

```
for x = 1, 16 do
  for y = 1, 16 do
    local cntr = Center:new()
    cntr.point = {x = 0.5 + x - 1, y = 0.5 + y - 1}
    centerLookup[cntr.point] = cntr
    table.insert(self.centers, cntr)
  end
end
```

In the code above, centerLookup[point] is meant to look up the respective Center object by inputting a point location.

However, when I try to do this:

```
function neighbors(center, sqrtsize)
  if center.point.y + 1 < sqrtsize then
    local up = {x = center.point.x, y = center.point.y+1}
    local centerup = centerLookup[up]
    table.insert(center.neighbors, centerup)
  end
end
```

centerup returns as a nil value

Idk if the problem is that I can't use a table as an index, but that is what I'm thinking.

Anybody know what's wrong here?

P.S. if it's helpful, centers start at 0.5 (so [0.5, 0.5] would be the first center, then [0.5, 1.5], etc.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with local variables and everything to do with the fact that tables are compared by-reference and not by-value.

In Lua, tables are reference types that have their own identity. Even if two tables have the same contents, Lua does not consider them equal unless they are the exact same object.

To illustrate this, here is some sample code, and the printed values:

```
local tbl1 = {x = 0.5, y = 0.5}
local tbl2 = tbl1
local tbl3 = {x = 0.5, y = 0.5}
print(tbl1 == tbl2) -- True; tbl1 and tbl2 both reference the same table
print(tbl1 == tbl3) -- False; tbl1 and tbl3 reference different tables
```

---

```
local up = {x = center.point.x, y = center.point.y+1}
local centerup = centerLookup[up]
```

In this snippet, `up` is a *completely new* table with only one reference (the `up` variable itself). This new table won't be a key in your `centerLookup` table, even if a table key exists with the same contents.

```
cntr.point = {x = 0.5 + x - 1, y = 0.5 + y - 1}
centerLookup[cntr.point] = cntr
table.insert(self.centers, cntr)
```

In this snippet, you create a new table, and reference it in three different places: `cntr.point`, `centerLookup` as a key, and `self.centers` as a value. You presumably iterate through the `self.centers` array, and use *the exact same table* to look up items in the `centerLookup` table. However, if you were to use a table not in the `self.centers` array, it would not work.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation, this is just what I was trying to figure out

Answer (score 2):

**Colonel Thirty Two** explained the reason why your code not working as expected. I just want to add quick solution:

```
function pointToKey(point)
  return point.x .. "_" .. point.y
end
```

Use this function for lookup in both places

```
--setup centerLookup
centerLookup[pointToKey(cntr.point)] = cntr

--find point from lookup
local centerup = centerLookup[pointToKey(up)]
```